# sticky nav below breakpoint not fixed to top

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm fairly new to Foundation and I searched for this answer everywhere, but couldn't find it.

Trying to create a page that has a navigation that starts half way of the page. When scrolling the navigation will stick to the top. That's easy and works like a charm..

But when you go onto the page with a smaller screen size I would like the 'mobile' menu to be fixed at top, not just floating around the page.

The div I have around my  is:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
```

Hope someone knows how I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options, you could just use a media query for small screens, something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
   .sticky {
      position: fixed !important;
      top: 0px !important;
   }
}
```

Or you could conditionally only load Magellan (or whichever method you are using) when the screen size is large enough, e.g.

```
if($(window).width() > 670){
   // init sticky nav stuff here
}
```